# Can you explain the use of sys.sp_addextendedproperty in the following code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, extended-properties

What's going on in the following code after the View is created? Can you give me any thoughts or path to follow?

This code is taken from [here](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4733#111285).

```
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vProductImages]    Script Date: 04/28/2008 16:59:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vProductImages]
AS
SELECT        dbo.Products_Images.ProductID, dbo.Images.ThumbUrl, dbo.Images.FullImageUrl
FROM            dbo.Products_Images INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Images ON dbo.Products_Images.ImageID = dbo.Images.ImageID
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "Products_Images"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 99
               Right = 208
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "Images"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 246
               Bottom = 116
               Right = 416
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 9
         Width = 284
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'vProductImages'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=1 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'vProductImages'
GO
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

It looks like you used the GUI designer to create the view.  In order to save the graphical layout of your tables in the designer, it's storing this metadata as an extended property.  It doesn't affect how the view is actually processed.  It's just so that you can run the designer again and have it look the way you left it.

Comment: wow! I'm trying to understand what's this code for, and I didn't find a clue. thanks :)

Comment: Can I configure SSMS not to do it?

Comment: @sprinter252, I can't find a way to disable this.

Comment: @David: I found one thing: If you use "Script database" you can go to the options there and disable scripting of extended properties. Thats the only point where I at least found something about it. Stupid in my eyes!

Comment: Nice! This is my first time encountering this and I began to think I missed one too many classes in college lol.

I figured it had something to do with an interface of some sort because of the *PaneConfiguration* & *@name=N'MS_DiagramPane1* stuff, I just didn't know if it was an SSMS thing or something that was somehow getting back to another application.

Comment: So we can delete this information from the view, perhaps to improve performance?

Comment: @Baodad, it is probably not worth your time to look into this.  If you are looking for performance improvements, this should be at the very, very bottom of your list.

Comment: Thank you so much. A lady at my job makes views and they always have this statement in it. I get confused because I think this is some sort of TSQL I should know, but this makes way more sense. She always makes tables from the design mode as opposed to the written out way.

Comment: Does the extended property affect the performance?
Does the GUI designer create less efficient Views? (I see a line with right join and right join again on the next line but neither line has the fields that the join is on)